# Getting syntax error running subtraction in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, subtraction

I am trying to run this code in python, but can't see what it won't work. I'm trying to create a new column populated based on subtracting one column from another.

```
CentreData1819('mean_difference') = CentreData1819['2019_mean'] - CentreData1819['2018_mean']
```

I'm getting SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Answer (score 0):

Change those parentheses to brackets :)

```
CentreData1819['mean_difference'] = CentreData1819['2019_mean'] - CentreData1819['2018_mean']
```